# Hide rectangle base on tablix value

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Good day.. I'm new to SSRS and i want to know, is there away to hide an SSRS rectangle base on tablix value..?

Thanks,

Link

Answer (score 0):

If the rectangle is not inside the same group of the tablix then no. If it is you can access the tablix value by using the `ReportItems!Textbox##.value` function (for example).

However, you can perform operations directly to the dataset that feeds the tablix either by using the normal aggregation functions or by using the `Lookup` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255275.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx